# How to save and get back a custom object in Android?

Tags: android, gson, sharedpreferences, reload

This topic [How to save a custom Java Object in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645492/how-to-save-to-save-a-custom-java-object-in-android) is what comes near enough for my solution but without success. So I have a custom object, that I would like to add to a Favorite list, which means that I would like to find my saved object anywhere in the app (all activities). But I don't know how to call in my activity (where is the favorite list) my shared preferences created in another activity, to after get back the json.

Comment: I believe Share Preferences you can access in different activity if you use default one.. or specific name..

Comment: Try to convert your custom object to a string. And save the string via the PreferencesManager.

Comment: @LucaZiegler what then ?

Comment: @ValayPatel, i tried to didnt work :/

Comment: SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); will give you default SP. Use GSON to convert your custom object to JSON string and store it as string.. Later fetch the string and using GSON convert that to Custom object of yours.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819294/save-custom-object-array-to-shared-preferences

Comment: @ValayPatel i tried it and it doesnt recognize mPrefs... his example must be in the same class

Comment: Can you put you whole code in example..Where mPrefs is defined??

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this is what i did:  addFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String myJson = gson.toJson(currentProduit);
                prefsEditor.putString("myproduct", myJson);
                prefsEditor.apply();
            }
   });                                                                                                             after that i dont know how to get it back in other class

Comment: This is my code for the shared preferences in one class SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String myJson = gson.toJson(currentProduit);
                prefsEditor.putString("myproduct", myJson);
                prefsEditor.apply();                                                              After that i dont know what to put in the other class to get back that data

Comment: In other class -->SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());String myJson= mPrefs.getString("myproduct") and than convert the myJSON string to your object using toObject method

Comment: @ValayPatel this line seems to require two strings String myJson = mPrefs.getString("myproduct", //missing?);

Comment: Thats the default value you have provide.. If there is no shared preference available.. Just put null for the time being and thing about the default value later on.

Comment: @ValayPatel thanks ! It worked, just had a question, can I store multiple objects my sharedpreferences ? EDIT: dont know if its possible to accept ur answer because its a comment ? (newbie to stack :D)

Comment: As much as you want.. Don't forget to up vote answer..

Comment: @ValayPatel your answer is a comment, there is not the tick to put in green to accept ur answer :/

Comment: @Jay added answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

will give you default SP. Use GSON to convert your custom object to JSON string and store it as string.. Later fetch the string and using GSON convert that to Custom object of yours.

In other class

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String myJson= mPrefs.getString("myproduct")
```

and than convert the myJSON string to your object using toObject method

Comment: When I will have 15 of reputation, I will up vote your answer haha

Answer (score 0):

Follow the android documentation on shared preference it contains details on how to create shared preference accessible in all activities [Android Documentaion on shared preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data as key-value in storage by using (Hawk library)
- you can save all data types and objects then retrieve it at any time.
the link on GitHub [Hawk Documentation](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk)
* your data will be encrypted in the storage

to save data

```
Hawk.init(context).build();
Hawk.put("key", "value");
```

to retrieve data

```
Hawk.init(context).build();
String s = Hawk.get("key");
```